# When installing ArcGIS Server 10.1, I cannot get the System/Publish service to start

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, installation

When I attempt to start it, it displays "System/Publishing Tools service is starting..." but never ends, time's out, or gives an error message.  Any ideas what is going on here?  I have already installed the license manager, ArcGIS Desktop and the license codes.  ArcGIS Server seems installed correctly but just won't start the publishing service.  I'm trying to develop with the ArcGIS Javascript API which is why I'm installing ArcGIS Server on my PC.

Comment: you will have to put more information into your question. you have authorized server? when do you get the message? in browser I assume. what browser/ver? can you see the rest endpoint? do you have any services? is this directly after install? It should already be started after install? what blockers, firewall software do you have installed?

Comment: Are you aware that with 10.1 their "simplification" requires that you install the service and execute data through the service before publishing it and having it usable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by installing the service and executing data through the service first.  For simplicity's sake let's say I have an MXD file with a single layer I want to publish.  In ArcMap if I go through the "Share as" menu and do the analyze and preview of the layer it works fine.  If I try to publish, I'm told the publisher service is not running.  If I go to the ArcGIS Server manager and attempt to "start" the publisher service, it just runs and apparently hangs.  What steps am I missing in this example?

Comment: I've have already tried disabling the local firewall software.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using ArcGIS Server 10.2 and did not have a problem.  I'm not sure if this was a glitch in the installation of 10.1 or how I setup 10.1 but either way I have been working fine with 10.2 and have not looked back.